# "The remote server returned an error: NotFound" Translator API Windows phone 8

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to figure out a way to make working the tutorial from MSDN blog I found on using Microsoft Translator (Azure marketplace) on a Windows Phone 8 app. here it is the link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/windowsphone8.aspx .
I'm using exactly the same code and sometimes I receive a:
    "The remote server returned an error: NotFound"

I really don't understand what I have to do! 
Can someone help me to find a stable way to use that translation API on Windows phone ?
thanks.

Comment: I encountered the same error.  did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the api credentials for the Azure translator service.

Answer (score 0):

Per the original poster, the problem was with the credentials that need to be provided to the API service.