# “The remote server returned an error: NotFound” Translator API Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization, microsoft-translator

I am trying out the example Windows Phone 8 app using Microsoft Bing Translator on MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/windowsphone8.aspx

I'm running the exact same code and sometimes I receive a: `The remote server returned an error: NotFound` error.

I am going nuts trying to resolve this error, as I don't know what's wrong. Can someone help me resolve this error?

Thank you.

P.S: This question has been asked before, but I'm just not sure what the solution is.

["The remote server returned an error: NotFound" Translator API Windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467954/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-notfound-translator-api-windows-phone-8)

Comment: have you generated API credential as described in [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted1.aspx)?

Comment: Are you receiving the errors only **sometimes** or always?

Comment: har07, yes I have generated the API credentials as per the link you provided.

Comment: Gaurav, I get the error sometimes. I'd say about 75% of the time.